# HttpResponse Set Cookies

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpresponse, setcookie

I'm making a POST request to Server A from Server B, Server A should return a cookie along with the HttpResponse, but it is never set.

What should i do ? Is there some middleware stuff i should be doing ? The domain needs to be set ?

I'm setting a value to maxAge, for HttpOnly and Samesite i'm using false value.

This is my request:

xhttp.open("POST", "http://analytics:5007/api/pixel", true);

xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(params));

This my endpoint:

```
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] QCStudent student)
    {
        CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
        option.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        option.HttpOnly = false;
        option.SameSite = 0;
        Response.Cookies.Append("qcpid", student.studentId, option);
        return Ok();
    }
```

This should the set the value of my studentId to my cookie, "qcpid", but instead nothing is set.

I find it weird because if i make the request to the controller of Server B, and use the same code, it works, what i'm doing wrong ?

Edit*: Here are some images, hopefully it describes my situation better.

[Http Header is set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h1OP.png)

[Browser has no Header for Set-Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orwLD.png)

Comment: If your request is sending a cookie and it is not expired, then you will not get a new cookie.  You can go to your IE and delete cookies and try again.

Comment: But i don't have this cookie on my browser, i even made a get request to check the cookie and it is not set

Comment: Verify with a sniffer.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 200 response from the server? Are you making this request from browser?

Comment: yes, i'm requesting it from the browser, Google Chrome, the code runs fine, it returns 200, he just ignores the Set-Cookie header,